# Get CSS font-weight value using Javascript style.fontWeight.value (getting undefined, expecting a value)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am aware that the value could sometimes be a word like "bold" but for this i am only using numbers and was expecting the output to show "900", instead i'm getting "undefined".

```js
document.getElementById("results").innerText = document.getElementById("getfontweightfrom").style.fontWeight.value;
```

```html
<div id="getfontweightfrom" style="font-weight:900;">
Test
</div>
<hr>
Result: <div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to add `.value`.

```js
document.getElementById("results").innerText = document.getElementById("getfontweightfrom").style.fontWeight;
```

```html
<div id="getfontweightfrom" style="font-weight:900;">
Test
</div>
<hr>
Result: <div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is window.getComputedStyle

```
const weight = window.getComputedStyle(elem).fontWeight
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need value property, just style.fontWeight

Answer (score 1):

You may use `getComputedStyle()`

```js
elem = document.getElementById('getfontweightfrom');
style = window.getComputedStyle(elem);
weight = style.fontWeight;
alert(style.fontWeight)
```

```html
<div id="getfontweightfrom" style="font-weight:900;">Test<div>
```